# Is autocompletion for applications done by shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, autocomplete

When I type `evince`, and then hit tab, the bash shell will list all files that can be opened by `evince`, which seems to be based on the ext part of the filename.

Is this done by shell or the application `evince`?

If former, how does the shell know what the application needs?

Comment: Have a look at the contents of `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`...

Comment: mine is `/etc/bash_completion`. I also have `/etc/bash_completion.d/`. what are their differences?

Comment: The full list of completion scripts should be in `/usr/share...` but it may vary on some distros. Packages that install their own completions tend to drop them in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`

Comment: here you find an answer of how to add auto completion to your scripts https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/489235/240990

Answer (score 2):

#### Runs in shell

There are two separate questions here:

Where is the completion **implemented**, and
Which other software component **does it belong to**.

The implementation of completion is interacting closely with the command line editor, which is part of the shell; It basically **needs to** run in the shell.

A large part of the completion is implemented as **shell functions** in most shells;

#### Separate package

You asked whether it is somehow part of the application, or part of the shell;
In practice, it is neither the first nor the second actually, but independent.

Most completions under Ubuntu are in the **separate package** `bash-completion`,
a large collection of the completions you might expect.
Is not part of bash, but managed and released independently.

#### Code

Let's take a look at your completion example for `evince`:

```
$ apt-file list bash-completion | grep evince
bash-completion: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/evince
$ ls -l /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/evince
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 967 Apr  7 16:10 /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/evince
```

Interesting! We did not need to look for something general like completion for PDF viewers, but found something directly related to `evince`.

The file contains a shell function implementation; Part of it consists of string constants that describe how `evince` can be used on the command line - the most interesting parts of [`/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/evince`](https://alioth.debian.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=bash-completion/bash-completion.git;a=blob_plain;f=completions/evince;hb=HEAD) are:

```
_evince() {
    [  ...  ]
    case $prev in --gdk-no-debug|--gtk-module|--gtk-debug|--gtk-no-debug|\
        -p|--page-label|-i|--page-index|-l|--find|--display)
    [  ...  ]
    _filedir '@(@(?(e)ps|?(E)PS|[pf]df|[PF]DF[...]|bmp|xpm|ico|xwd|tga|pcx)'
    [  ...  ]
```

It describes general options like `--gtk-debug`, application speciffic options like `--page-label`, and lists file name extensions that can be handeled by `evince` like `.eps` and `.pdf`.

#### Hands on

You can show functions defined in the current shell with the `declare` builtin. If you try that in a new shell, you get an error message:

```
$ declare -f -p _evince
bash: declare: _evince: not found
```

Assuming the package `bash-completion` is installed, this just meas that the function in not yet loaded.
Because there are a **large number** of functions like this, and in one interactive shell session, only a few are used, it makes sense to only load functions when they are really needed, instead of loading all at startup.

To get the function loaded, we try to use it, by using the `evince` completion. With the cursor at the location of `|`, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key;

```
$ evince -|<TAB>
```

There may be some completion shown. Now, the function should be loaded, and look like in the file above if we print it:

```
$ declare -f -p _evince
```

To list all function names, or see all functions that are currently loaded - including ones that are unrelated to completion, use:

```
$ declare -F | less
$ declare -f | less
```