# Make bash-autocomplete recognize certain filetype for certain script

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete

How can I make `bash` recognize a certain filetype for a specific `script`?

for example, I wrote a tiny script to compile a `lilypond-file` and then automatically open the compiled `pdf`:

```
#!/bin/bash

run() {
    lilypond "$1"
    name=$(basename "$1" .ly)
    if [ -f "${name}.pdf" ]; then
        xpdf -cont -remote LilyPreview "${name}.pdf" &
    else
        printf "\\n file %s.pdf is not present..!\\n\\n" "$name"
    fi
}

run "$@"
```

how can I make `bash` know, to only suggest `*.ly` files from the folder and ignore `*.pdf` and `*.midi` files with the same basename.

---

**Update 2.3:**

so when I want to run: `script.sh myfile.ly`, then bashs autocomplete also suggests `myfile.pdf` and `myfile.midi` if they are present. I want bash to know that this script only wants to read `*.ly` files (rather as a matter of convenience).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by autocomplete? How do you want to call the script?

Comment: @nath If you run `script.sh myfile.ly`, why should the other filenames matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `~/.bashrc`, you could add something like this to enable autocompletion for your `script.sh`:

`complete -f -X '!*.ly' script.sh`

The `-f` option specifies filenames, and `-X` is the filter pattern (note that the filter pattern removes values matching the pattern, so `!` is used to negate the pattern such that all filenames except `*.ly` are removed.

Comment: nice, thanks. Would there be an option to allow folders to be displayed?

Comment: @nath yes, you can specify `-o plusdirs` to `complete` to add directories to the list.